# One- and Two-Electron Integrals: Values of $p, q, r, s$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, second-quantization

In the second quantization, the molecular Hamiltonian can be written as:

[image]

where $p, q, r, s$ denote general spin-orbitals.

What values and arrangements can $p, q, r, s$ take?

For instance, I have seen the one-electron integral for the minimal (STO-3G) basis model of H2 expressed as:

[image]

Does this imply $p = q$?

Similarly, the two-electron integral for the minimal (ST)-3G) basis model of H2 follows:

[image]

What happened to other values such as:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indices are generically unrestricted. In typical ab initio quantum chemistry approaches, one truncates the Fock space up to some finite number $ N $ of spin orbitals. Then all of $ p,q,r,s $ can range from $ 1 $ to $ N $.

That said, there are some properties of the Hamiltonian itself that lead to the absence of various permutations. For instance, a trivial one is the fact that $ a_p^2 = (a_p^\dagger)^2 = 0 $ for all $ p $. Thus, in the two-body component, all terms with either $ p = q $ or $ r = s $ trivially vanish (e.g. $ h_{11}^{11} = 0 $ always).

Beside that, you have to consider the system (molecule) that your Hamiltonian actually describes. Not every molecular integral is nonzero. In fact, many molecules are typically "sparse" in this sense: because of spatial or spin symmetries, or due to your choice of basis set, many of the coefficients will evaluate to $ 0 $.

Finally, because the STO-3G basis uses real-valued spatial orbital functions (as do almost all standard basis sets featured in the computational chemistry literature), you have many symmetries in the integrals themselves. In particular, real-valued orbitals means that
$$ h_{pq} = h_{qp}, $$
$$ h_{rs}^{pq} = h_{rp}^{sq} = h_{qs}^{pr} = h_{qp}^{sr}. $$
(You can check these by examining the definition of the integrals and observing that the complex conjugation does nothing to real-valued functions.) Additionally, due to the canonical anticommutation relations, $ a_p^\dagger a_q^\dagger a_r a_s = a_q^\dagger a_p^\dagger a_s a_r $, which gives yet another symmetry,
$$ h_{rs}^{pq} = h_{sr}^{qp} $$
(note that this particular identity holds even if using complex-valued orbitals). In total, this gives an eightfold symmetry in the two-body integrals.

The molecular hydrogen Hamiltonian that you've written down is likely utilizing all such symmetries, and thus the expression is "maximally simplified" (in the sense of whichever computational chemistry package was used to produce it).

In summary: $ p,q,r,s $ can each take on any value in $ \{1,\ldots,N\} $, where $ N $ is the number of spin orbitals specified by the model chemistry. However, there is a lot of structure in the Hamiltonian and many symmetries in the molecule/molecular orbitals that cause various terms (coefficients) to vanish. In the example you've posed, a computer system likely already took into account all those symmetries and simplified the expression for the Hamiltonian dramatically.